# UBER -404- Authentication - invalid grant

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, uber-api, http-status-code-400

We are on Development Stage , Till now don't have Full Access for everyone , Only 5 Developers we are using and Testing the API . getting issue in authentication
Iam following the doc

[uberauthentication_docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token)

for Authenticate User with My App and getting Access token .And Using that access token for every API like(request,estimate,products...e.t.c).

It is working fine till yesterday but from today morning iam getting error as invalid grant. My Doubt is in Uber docs we will get Redirect URI like this

```
https://your-redirect-uri/?code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>
```

But Iam getting as

```
https://your-redirect-uri/?code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>&state=3D64bjJo_WtoXLC54cap3TPV2CDo2toJup82pSLXDXfRo%253D%23_
```

But Still iam spliting or extract the code from Redirect URI and taking only
`AUTHORIZATION_CODE`
and passing in Token Exchange End Point and getting error as invalid grant.
Note : My Redirect URI is only one in DashBoard

My Request is like below

Step 1 : Loading Authorization URL in web view

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>
```

And Getting Redirect URI As

```
https://your-redirect-uri/?code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>&state=3D64bjJo_WtoXLC54cap3TPV2CDo2toJup82pSLXDXfRo%253D%23_
```

Step2 : passing `AUTHORIZATION_CODE` in Token Exchange API

```
`curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \
 -F 'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>' \
 -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
 -F 'redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>' \
 -F 'code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FROM_STEP_2>' \
 https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
```

`
like this but getting error as invalid grant.
Please check and help me out from this problem.

Comment: What is wrong with Question ? Why

Comment: Hello-- I know the team that works on identity at Uber just rolled back some changes. Can you try the same thing you are currently doing now and reply on if it works or you are still having trouble?

Comment: Okay .I will try

Comment: Now it is working..Is this issue from your end Kyle Davis